# How can I use struct defined in one class in a different class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have this struct in a class, `Class1`.:

```
static struct count {
    int member1;
    int member2;
    int member3;
} count1, count2, count3;
```

In `Class1`, I will be incrementing all three of the `count` variables and using it again in `Class2` in a separate file.  How can I do this?  Do I need to include `Class1` in a header file?

Comment: Are you sure this is correctly tagged [tag:c++]?? The usual way is to make the declaration visible to the other class (yes, include the header file where you need to see the `count1,count2,count3`).

Answer (score 0):

the static variables scope is limited but lifetime is through out the program, if you have declare the count structure inside the class1 definition then you cant access this static count object in Class2 even though you include the file where Class2 has been defined.
You have to make count structure global in the file and then can include the file to access it in Class2